# How to get cloned option's attributes of select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="simpleSelect"  multiple>
<option type='string'>raj</option>
<option type='number'>1</option>
</select>
<script>
$(function(){
var cloneOptions = $('#simpleSelect option').clone();
console.log(cloneOptions.length); // 2
console.log(cloneOptions[0]); //<option type="string">raj</option>
console.log(cloneOptions[0].length); //undefined
console.log(typeof cloneOptions[0]); //object
});
</script>
```

How to get the value of type attribute.
It is weird even it is object length is undefined.
Any help appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(cloneOptions[0]).attr('type')
```

Comment: Thanks it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`cloneOptions` has cloned object of 2 option elements.`cloneOptions[0]` returns the dom object of first element.

you need to use `.eq()` selector to get jquery object of element by index:

```
cloneOptions.eq(0).attr('type');
```

also `type` is not valid attribute for option element. You should rather use `data-*` attributes for adding custom attributes:

```
<option data-type='string'>raj</option>
```

and then use `.data()` to get the data attribute value"

```
 cloneOptions.eq(0).data('type');
```

Comment: I am new to UI development.
Thanks for the intimation about data-*, i missed it completely.

Comment: @Sandeepsandy: glad it helps :)